# Add the checking if supplier active

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code

```
var events = Filter(context.Events.AsNoTracking())
            .Select(e => new EventDto
                             {
                                 Id = e.Id,
                                 SupplierId = e.SupplierId,
                                 Supplier = e.Supplier.FullName,
                                 DocumentType = e.DocumentType.Title,
                                 ScheduledDate = e.ScheduledDate
                             })
            .ToList();

var suppliers = events.Select(e => e.SupplierId).ToList();
        var eventsBySupplier = events.GroupBy(e => e.SupplierId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
        LogEvents(eventsBySupplier);

var subscriptions = context.Subscriptions.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(e => e.User)
            .Include(e => e.Supplier)
            .Include(e => e.Supplier.Responsible)
            .Where(e => suppliers.Contains(e.SupplierId))
            .Where(e => notifiedRoles.Contains(e.User.Role))
            .ToList();
        LogSubscriptions(subscriptions);
```

and I need to add here the checking if Supplier is active.

Supplier has a property

```
public bool Active { get; set; }
```

so I need to add the checking if `e.Active == active`, but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
.Where(e => suppliers.Contains(e.SupplierId))
```

to

```
.Where(e => suppliers.Contains(e.SupplierId) && e.Active == active)
```